# Resetting setInterval count to zero

Tags: count, setinterval, reset

I would like my count to reset back to zero after it reaches a specified number. Could someone help me adjust this?

```
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
var count = 0;
var myCount;

  if(count === 0) {
  myCount = setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  },1000)
  } else if(count === 5){
  clearInterval(myCount)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
var count = 0;
var specifiedNumber = 5;
var myCount;
var increasing = true;

  myCount = setInterval(function(){
    count++; 
    counter.innerHTML = count;
    if(count==specifiedNumber ){
       count=0;
    }
  },1000)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this only stops my count at five, My goal is to try and  reset it back to zero and  have it count back up once it hits the specified number.

Comment: dont understand
like: from 0 to specified number and back to 0 ?
can you give a example

Comment: For example I mean the count would go from 0-5, then after it reaches 5. The count resets back to 0 and starts over again.

Comment: changed my answer

Comment: Thanks this worked except for the count-- i changed it to '0' as I wanted the count to totally reset instead of decrement. Thank you!

Comment: sorry I understand wrong . here is new correct code